# Issue with mouseenter in jQuery

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

I have one button and span tags inside it like

```
<div class="someclass" style="border: 0px solid black;padding: 5px 5px 5px 0px;width: 50px;">
    <button class="eventBound" type="button">
        <span>
            <span>text for button</span>
        </span>
        <div class="hiddenDiv"></div>
    </button>
</div>
```

and have jQuery code like

```
jQuery(".eventBound").mouseenter(function () {
    someFunctionToOpenBox(required parameters);
});
```

From above code I am able to open overlay box when I hovers mouse on button from top direction but it does not open overlay box when I hovers mouse on button from bottom direction.

What could be the case by this malfunctioning?

Comment: can you show it through jsfiddle?

Comment: for me it is working perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/BwC2x/

Comment: issue is with the function. add the function in the question if you want clear answer

Comment: There might be a hidden element or something else on that button to prevent firing mousenter. Can you share your relevant css too?

Answer (score 2):

[ITS WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X2ydF/)

```
<div class="someclass" style="border: 0px solid black;padding: 5px 5px 5px 0px;width: 50px;">
    <button class="eventBound" type="button">
        <span>
            <span>text for button</span>
        </span>
        <div class="hiddenDiv"></div>
    </button>
</div>

$(".eventBound").mouseenter(function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```

I Thing Issue with your  `someFunctionToOpenBox(required parameters);`